# incorrect uv unwrapping for simple plane shape

Tags: uv

Whenever I make this simple shape with a plane and unwrap it, it unwraps into a weird shape:

[image]

I know I can unwrap with project from view or cube projection to get the correct shape so I'm not after a solution per se, I'm looking for an explanation about what's the cause and why it happens as well as it it's a bug or not. 
from what I've tested it happens whenever there's a long rectangle attached to another one, as the shape get bigger and become longer the uv start to twist in weird shapes,

- I did apply the scale and it's not the issue here.
- The corners are exactly 90 degrees
- the scales are 20cm*280cm with 2cm extra width on each side at the
  base for 10cm if you want to make that exact shape

Edit: as you can see, a shorter version unwraps correctly as well as the one I changed some of those 90 degrees angles:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here you go:

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4205/

Comment: When I open your file, select the poorly unwrapped mesh, and u->unwrap, it gives me a what I'd expect.  Try again.  There's some reason that it's taking that shape that you're not mentioning (like since-deleted geometry.)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to unwrap an n-gon. Fill in the missing edges, and the unwrap will look as expected.

[image]

After that, you can delete the three edges using "limited dissolve", if you want to keep working with an n-gon. The UVs will stay the same.

Comment: well it's not because it's an n-gon, there should be another reason.

Comment: That some n-gons seem to be working, is no reason to say "there should be another reason". I just can answer your question, whether you try to acknowledge this and start working with proper topology is completely up to you.

Comment: my question wasn't about proper topology, it's about why does this problem in unwrapping happens, and I know the answer is not "because its an n-gon"

Answer (score 0):

Try select this when unwrap:

> Method: Conformal